# Issue with inserting an SVG inside a table cell

Tags: tables, graphics, svg

I'm trying to create a table that has merged rows and columns, images, and an SVG.

I successfully included the images but I'm struggling with the SVG, somehow, it doesn't want to fit into the attributed cell.

Here is syntax:

```latex
\documentclass[15pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{|llll|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{red} \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\includegraphics{1_short}}     & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\huge FICHE D'EXTRACTION} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Le 23/03/2022} \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                   & Urgence 1                          \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm,keepaspectratio]{bien1.jpeg} \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm,keepaspectratio]{bien2.jpeg}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\includesvg[width=10cm]{map-0}}   \\ \cline{1-3}
            \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Inputs liées à Ste Marie}                                &                                    \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Logo sinistre} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Extraction}                                              \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Logo sinistre} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Sensible aux éclaboussures}                              \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Logo sinistre} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Protection}                                              \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

I had hopes that `\includegraphics{}` and `\includesvg{}` would work the same way, but I'm getting this kind of result when generating my document (using `pdflatex`):

[image]

Please note that the table is a screenshot from a landscape image, but rotated for a better lisibility. The problem still exists even without the rotation.

I don't know what I should do, should I generate an image from the SVG before generating the document, or is there a "native" way to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Edit : I updated the minimal working example

Comment: Try `\raisebox{\depth}{\includesvg[width=10cm]{map-0}}`.

Comment: @RuixiZhang The svg is now sliiiightly more in the cell, but just by a centimeter, the huge part of it is still outside

Comment: Hmm, this is strange. Perhaps the SVG file itself does not report its dimensions correctly? Try `\raisebox{10cm}{\includesvg[width=10cm]{map-0}}` then, or any other raise amount you like.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I updated my questions, my apologizes

Comment: The example is no MWE as I can't replicate your issue without your graphics. Please consider to use `example-image.jpg` (shipped with package `mwe`) for `includegraphics` commands. For the SVG file you could either use `svg-example.svg` located at `<TEX_DIR>/doc/latex/svg` or paste the content of your file within
`\begin{filecontents}{mwe-sample.svg}...\end{filecontents}` and use it with `\includesvg{mwe-sample}`

Comment: Hard to say without an MWE, but I'd guess you want to say `\usepackage[inkscapearea=page]{svg}` and delete the `svg-inkscape` folder.